# subtract two numbers in base 3 in java

Tags: java, math, int, integer-arithmetic

What's going on here? I'm trying to subtract two integers in the base 3 system.

```
int x=222211;
int y=112222;

String result = Integer.toString(x-y,3);
```

and the result is `109989`
but the answer should be `102212`

It seems clear that the library doesn't do what I think it does - the result I'm getting is the base 10 result of that subtraction. Converting this result to base 3 gives me a wildly incorrect result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is embarrassing, but I figured it out seconds after posting this... but maybe it will help someone else out.

```
int x = Integer.parseInt("222211",n);
int y = Integer.parseInt("112222",n);

String result = Integer.toString(x-y,n);
```

convert the numbers beforehand to the appropriate base